# Can you make calls to an external api from with a SCORM course

Tags: scorm, scorm1.2

I am playing around with making some e-learning content that is SCORM 1.2 compliant. However, it seems that you must package everything to be delivered and used on an LMS. Is it still possible to make calls to an external server? I assume it is but is this bad practice?

An example for clarification:
Say I have a service running on an external server that I cannot wrap to deliver to the LMS. However, I would still like to make requests to it. Can this be done from a SCORM course as a user is doing the course?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the call, but as you point out it would be a bad practice.

Essentially you'd have no trust of who or what is making the call because you can't put a secure credential in front of it and the call itself (or an authentication request prior to the call) would be susceptible to MITM attacks.

If you were simply loading an insecure resource then you could do that, CORS would apply.

Having said that, you may be interested in the Rustici Cross Domain product https://rusticisoftware.com/products/rustici-cross-domain/ (full disclosure I work for Rustici).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will have a look into your RXD product.